# Mat-autocomplete search on multiple field at the same time

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a mat-autocomplete containing 5000 objects. Each objects contains a first-name and a last name.

I would like to be able to search on both first-name and last-name at the same time no matter the order the input is entered. At the moment I'm only able to search on one of the two fields at the time.

```
private _filterClients(value: string): any[] {
    const filterValue = value.toLowerCase();
    return this.options.filter(option => 
        option.first_name.toLowerCase().indexOf( filterValue ) > -1 || 
        option.last_name.toLowerCase().indexOf( filterValue ) > -1
   );
}
```

My goal is that when I type Bill Ga... I get the most probable suggestion. Same thing if I type Gate Bi...

I'm not sure how to implement this. Your help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is a complicated problem, sometimes we do not contemplate that there are compound names. Which we cannot differentiate which is the middle name, or which is the first surname, or second surname as in my country, so I would try an implementation like this:

```
let filterValues : string[] = value.toLowerCase().split(" ");
let results : any[][];
let arrayAux: any[][];

/**
 * We identify which of the options contains each of the words incorporated 
 * in the filter, the idea is if we introduce 2 words, obtain an array of 2
 * positions, the first will be the options that contain the first word and the
 * next the second word, regardless of if it is in the first or last name.
 */
filterValues.forEach((filterValue : string) => {
    results.push(this.options.filter(option => 
            option.first_name.toLowerCase().indexOf( filterValue ) > -1 || 
            option.last_name.toLowerCase().indexOf( filterValue ) > -1);
});

/**
 * Once we have an array for each word entered in the filter, we must 
 * obtain the options that are repeated in all the lists.
 */
if (results.length > 0){
    arrayAux.concat(results[0]);
    
    results.forEach((result: string[]) => {
        arrayAux.concat(result);
        arrayAux = arrayAux.filter((e, i, a) => a.indexOf(e) !== i);
    });
}

return arrayAux;
```

An example so that you understand the compound names since it does not happen in all countries, for example in my country Spain, the singer Julio Iglesias his real name is "Julio José Iglesias de la Cueva", being Julio Jose his name, Iglesias the first surname and de la Cueva the second surname.

Due to this type of names, it is necessary to compare with all the words in the filter, since automatically in the same input for the filter it is not possible to know which one corresponds to the first name, first surname, etc.